# WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken and WebSecurity.ResetPassword, data operation failed error

Tags: c#, security

I have migrated my old users to simpleMembership tables, I've done it cycling all records and creating new users with:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(oldEmail, clearPassword);
```

Now when an user tries to reset his password with:

```
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(oldEmail,60);
```

A system.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException  : Database operation failed exception is thrown.
I'm really going crazy with this error, I thought using WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount was saving me from troubles as it's doing the same operation when a new user is created, but it seems something is missing in my code.. Please help!

Comment: Found the reason after hours of trials, when your DB is in replication, a "msrepl_tran_version" column is added to the tables. Well this is breaking SimpleMembership magic! After removing tables from replica and removing that column, everithing went just fine! Good to know!